Is there a way in Excel we can add some additional string to the existing column?
Let's say we have a column with values 100,101,102 and so on, we want to concat string "A" at the end of this without using another column's help like we can do the concat of value column 101 with string A. Was wondering if we can acheive this with any inbuilt functions or any other simple logic to do this?
Trying to use concat function on the same column where I've the data to be concatenated with a string value. This throws the error

Yes you can. So how does your data actually look like? And how do you want it to look like in the end? This currently sounds like you can do A1:A3&"A". You talking about an error using CONCAT(). Please can you also include your attempted formula.

What is your Excel version? What formula do you tried?

So, I'm preparing some sample data for my testing and wondering if I can do this directly in the column. Sample data: TP100000PT00UC001
TP100000PT00UC002
TP100000PT00UC003
TP100000PT00UC004
TP100000PT00UC005
TP100000PT00UC006
TP100000PT00UC007 ..
to this, I needed to add string A at the end. I was trying to CONCAT(A$1,"A"), but that is incorrect.

@UCN Your formula is almost correct. Just unlock row number. Try =CONCAT(A1,"A")

without using another column's help. The only way is using VBA if you want the string to be part of the value.

I can think of two ways of doing it without using another column's help.

Give the cells a custom format of @\A.
This won't actually add the A onto the text as can be seen in the formula bar, but an A will appear within the cell to the right of the text.

Use some VBA to add the A onto each cell in your selection:



Sub Add_An_A()

    Dim rCell As Range
    For Each rCell In Selection.Cells
        rCell = rCell & "A"
    Next rCell

End Sub

Otherwise you'll have to use a helper column to do it:
=A1 & "A" - you can then copy this and paste special values only back into column A (Ctrl+Shift+V to paste values only in 365).

Brilliant! I loved both these options. Thank you Darren! Appreciate it.

A Worksheet Change: Append a String


This code runs automatically.
Starting with cell A2, once you change (enter) a value in column A, an "A" is appended if the value is not an error or blank.
To open the correct window for the code, right-click on the tab and select View Code.

Sheet Module, e.g. Sheet1
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error GoTo ClearError

    Const FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "A2"
    Const SUFFIX As String = "A"
    
    Dim trg As Range, tRowsCount As Long
    
    With Me.Range(FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS)
        Set trg = .Resize(Me.Rows.Count - .Row + 1)
    End With
    
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(trg, Target)
    If irg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Dim icell As Range, iValue As Variant
    
    For Each icell In irg.Cells
        iValue = icell.Value
        If Not IsError(iValue) Then ' is no error
            If Len(iValue) > 0 Then ' is not blank
                icell.Value = iValue & SUFFIX
            End If
        End If
    Next icell

ProcExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub

